# Eslint "No files matching the pattern "lint" were found. Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern." error

Tags: javascript, eslint, package.json

recently I have updated my project eslint package to `"eslint": "^6.8.0"`. And this is when I'm seeing the error

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 6.8.0.

No files matching the pattern "lint" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.
```

My package JSON script looks like this:

```
"lint": "eslint lint --color src -f ./node_modules/eslint-friendly-formatter src/ tests/unit/__mocks__/ --ext .json --ext .js -c .eslintrc.js",
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with this script, it was wroking fine with the older verisons of eslint.

When looking for a solution in the forums, the suggestion is to add a flag 
`--no-error-on-unmatched-pattern`. I'm not sure why do I need to add this flag to my script.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: what was the previous version?

Comment: @A.Ametov this was the version I'm using ```"eslint": "^3.19.0",```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess people have faced this issue on verison 5 as well.. See this issue

https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/10587

`--no-error-on-unmatched-pattern` was added to ignore this kind of problem.

Comment: had this issue too with `eslint-summary-formatter`, `--sort-by` does not work as it is considered as a file pattern, hence the fix: `npx eslint -f summary --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern file.js -- --sort-by rule`